# Undefined method 'pathname' for #<#<Class:0x0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stylesheet

I updated Ruby and Rails version of my project.

Ruby `2.2.3` –> `2.5.1`

Rails `4.1.8` –> `5.1.7`

Now when I start the server, I get this error:

```
F, [2020-02-03T11:15:49.912385 #92132] FATAL -- : ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `pathname' for #<#<Class:0x00007f8f8859d7c8>:0x00007f8f8a06a2b8>
Did you mean?  path_to_image):
F, [2020-02-03T11:15:49.913172 #92132] FATAL -- :     21: 
    22:     %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Rado"
    23:     = csrf_meta_tags
    24:     = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: 'all'
```

My *application.css*:

```
 *= require_tree ./lib
 *= require_directory .
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.fileupload
 *= require jquery.fileupload-ui
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *= require switchery
 ...and some css
```

Error doesn't depend on the contents of *application.css*. I tried to delete everything in file, but error still appears.

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CTO5.png)

If I run `rake assets:precompile`, I get same error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `pathname' for #<#<Class:0x00007fea873db638>:0x00007fea80715df0>
Did you mean?  path_to_image
```

Comment: there is a chance of error during the compiling of CSS assets. try executing: rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=<production or development>

Comment: Are you using less-rails, Please check here is something which is identical to your issue https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/issues/152

Comment: @Fernand I still get `undefined method 'pathname'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the error occurred because I had `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem installed and *`bootstrap_and_overrides.less`* file was in *stylesheets* folder to use Less stylesheets.

So I just installed static stylesheets - `rails generate bootstrap:install static`

File *`bootstrap_and_overrides.less`* was renamed to `*bootstrap_and_overrides.css*` and replaced contents with:

```
/*
  *=require twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap
  Static version of css will use Glyphicons sprites by default
  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites
*/
```

If you also use this gem, [look at Github](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails).

But I still can not understand why this error appeared.